# Recorded audio with MediaRecorder can't be played with MediaPlayer

Tags: android

I am recording my voice with '.aac' format by using Android MediaRecorder. In high API levels like 22 and 25 these '.aac' files have no problems but in api 17, some of these voice files can not be played.

These random files can be played in ExoPlayer in API 17 but ExoPlayer starts with some delay and I don't want it, so I prefer to using MediaPlayer (but MediaPlayer can't play them).

Comment: Any error ?? also paste your code

Comment: there is a list of supported audio formats in the android documentation. Have you checked it?

Comment: I think this format is supported because just some of recorded files can not be played, in random.